# Resource for model organism anatomy/physiology for biological experiments

Tags: experimental-design

I'm looking for a resource that best surveys the anatomy and physiology of common genetic model organisms, and how their characteristics are particularly useful for biological experiments.

*For example*, I'm studying the eyeless Drosophila gene, but it would help to know that species' specific compound eye anatomy and normal development, so that I can weigh the pros and cons of using that particular model organism over another.

Comment: I don't think you will find a global DB like that. You will probably need to use [flybase](http://www.flybase.org), [mousebase](http://www.mousebase.org), [dictybase](http://www.dictybase.org/), [wormbase](http://www.wormbase.org) etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Bgee database](http://bgee.unil.ch/bgee/bgee), you can look at gene expression and anatomy of various model species, e.g. [Drosophila](http://bgee.unil.ch/bgee/bgee?page=anatomy&action=organs&stage_children=on&species_id=7227&stage_id=FBdv:00005369). This doesn't give you the full anatomy, but at least an ontology of tissues and cell types.